# ERROR: Need an adjoint for constructor Pair{Int64,Array{Float64,1}}

Tags: julia

```
using Flux
model = Chain(Dense(N+1, N), x -> x .+ [i for i in 1:N], x->relu.(x));
p1, re = Flux.destructure(model);
ps = Flux.params(p1);

using NLsolve
using Algebra

const rho = 20.0;
const con = [ones(1,N+1);  zeros(N, N+1)];
solve_x(p) = nlsolve(x -> (diagm(-1 => fill(rho, N), 0 => [0.0; fill(-rho, N) .- re(p)(x)], 1 => [0.0; re(p)(x)[2:end]])*x .+ con * x .- [1.; zeros(N)]), [1.; zeros(N)]).zero[20]

function loss_adjoint()
        solve_x(p1)
end
Flux.train!(loss_adjoint, ps, Iterators.repeated((), 1), ADAM(0.005))

ERROR: Need an adjoint for constructor Pair{Int64,Array{Float64,1}}. Gradient is of type ChainRulesCore.Composite{Pair{Int64,Array{Float64,1}},NamedTuple{(:second,),Tuple{Array{Float64,1}}}}
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::String) at ./error.jl:33
 [2] (::Zygote.Jnew{Pair{Int64,Array{Float64,1}},Nothing,false})...
```

When I run the above code, the error occurs. How to add `adjoint` method for `diagm`? Can somebody help me for this problem?

Comment: The code has been simplified and I just want to ask how to use the @adjoint in Zygote for LinearAlgebra.diagm constructor.

Comment: `x .+ [i for i in 1:N]` can be simplified to `x .+ 1:N`, I guess.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time.  It raises a new problem 'ERROR: MethodError: no method matching (::Colon)(::Array{Float64,1}, ::Int64)'. I think an adjoint method is needed for diagm of Pair, but I do not know how to specify it.

Comment: Oh, sorry, that's totally unrelated. The error is raised because `+` binds stronger than `:`, and I should've written `x .+ (1:N)`.

Comment: Thanks! Solution can be found at https://github.com/FluxML/Zygote.jl/issues/570#issuecomment-671420311